# How to test no internet connection program on emulator?

Tags: android, android-manifest

If an android program has a loop that is executed only when there is no internet access, how do you test it on emulator?

Removing internet access permission form manifest maybe one way. I'm sure other have come across this situation before. Is there an alternate way?

Answer (score 2):

Press `F8` to toggle network connection.

I used this in my emulator.

See this link [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to press F8 to check connection on your emulator.
You can turn on/off ariplane mode.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on airplane mode or turn off wifi on the pc you are running emulator on. The emulator wont't disconnect from debug and has no internet connection.